# My 'if int(time.time()) % 2 == 0:' doesn't always print out even sec

Tags: python

```
start = int(time.time())

while True:  

    if int(time.time()) % 2 == 0:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        saveas = 'screenshot' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png'
        img.save(saveas)

    elif start + 30 == int(time.time()):
        break
```

result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqdv6.png

Hi guys. It's a simple code but not working accurately.
I wanted to save a screenshot of my screen for every 2 seconds.
but in the result, I have some of those odd second files like 'screenshot1552893309.png'. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: That may be because `ImageGrab.grab()` taking time and calling `'screenshot' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png'` again will result in an odd second? If you store the value of `time.time()` in a variable and use that to check for oddity and file name, you should get consistent results.

Comment: Don't call `time.time()` more than once per loop if you don't want to get potentially different results from each call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because "time flies."

You are calling `time.time()` at most three times per iteration of the while loop.

Each call of `time.time()` returns the UNIX time at the given call. In your code, each call can be invoked at different seconds (thus returning different timestamps.)

For example, consider this situation: `time.time()` from `if int(time.time()) % 2 == 0:` returns `1552893308.0`, so the condition is satisfied, but the next call returns `1552893309.0`, which will leave its trace to the file name.

Instead, you might want to call `time.time()` only once per iteration, and then do what you want with that timestamp.

```py
start = int(time.time())

while True:  
    current_time = int(time.time())
    if current_time % 2 == 0:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        saveas = 'screenshot' + str(current_time) + '.png'
        # or you can also say
        # saveas = f'screenshot{current_time}.png'
        img.save(saveas)

    elif start + 30 <= current_time:
        break
```

Note the change of the boolean operator in `elif`. `start + 30 == current_time` seems too vulnerable to making a infinite loop.

Also note the commented use of f-strings, which was introduced in Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:  
    # save time into variable:
    start = int(time.time())    
    if start % 2 == 0:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        # use start time for file name:
        saveas = 'screenshot' + str(start) + '.png'
        img.save(saveas)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `time`, where you check it for even and the `time` where you are using it to save image would be different since they are in **different statement**. You can save the current time in every iteration, and use the saved time in image files name if its even.

*Sample code :*

```
while True:  
    t = int(time.time())
    if t % 2 == 0:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        saveas = 'screenshot' + str(t) + '.png'
        img.save(saveas)
```